# How do I control the visiblity of an exposed filter in a taxonomy term view?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I've activated the "taxonomy term" (the one that has the description "A view to emulate Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term.") view and I need to use it to:

1. expose a filter to the user
2. only display it on certain taxonomy
   pages

My example is this: I've got two vocabularies that are both being controlled by this view. We'll call them Restaurants and Working Locations. Both are "places" with phyical locations and I use the taxonomy display pages to list the various locations. I've also added an exposed filter that users can use to select a particular region for different "restaurants", but I do not want that filter to be on the "working locations" at all. I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've looked at Views Dependent Filters, but I can't get it to work the way I'd like.

So my question is how can I use the exposed filter to show on some taxonomy view pages, but not on others? The traditional filters of content type have not worked.

I'm looking at Rules, and or Contexts to see if this might be an option but I've still not found anything.

Any reason why the "exposed filter as block" option is not available to me in this view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in views to display your exposed filters in a block. In this usecase, if you only have one exposed filter, it might work for you to put the exposed filter in a block and then identify the pages you want to display it on in the block administration page.

You could use url aliases and a wildcard * to isolate all terms of a certain vocabulary to save you listing each page in the block admin form.

To put the exposed view in the block: Click on the advanced tab over on the right of the views pane and change 'Exposed form in block:' from No to Yes.

Comment: I like that idea, and saw some stuff on it earlier, but I'm not seeing an option to put that filter in a block.

Comment: You click on the advanced tab over on the right of the views pane and change 'Exposed form in block:' from No to Yes.

Comment: Found it - staring at this stuff too long. Let me see what I can do now.